# Photoshop shortcut for collapsing folders with square brackets?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I'm working in a very complex Photoshop document with many folders. I'm quite shortcut-savvy and use the square brackets + control and alt keys to select layers, reorder them, etc.

What would make my life much easier is if I could collapse folders using keyboard shortcut instead of collapsing them by clicking on the disclosure triangles.

For instance, if I could select a folder with ALT/OPTION [ , expand it with **CTRL + ALT + ]** (as an idea), check the contents, and then collapse it again with **CTRL + ALT + [** (as an idea), that would make a world of difference to my workflow.

Does anyone know if this kind of shortcut exists?

Answer (score 2):

Closing groups isn't scriptable and isn't actionable (sorry for the bad news).

You can option-click on a group to collapse or expand everything further down the hierarchy. So, you can close all groups in a document with a single click.

If you'd like a shortcut, I recommend posting on [feedback.photoshop.com](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can control layer group collapsing in any way other than a mouse click. I don't even think it's scriptable.

Your idea is a good one, but I don't believe there's any way to implement it currently. it would take some alteration on the part of Adobe to allow shortcut assignments or something.

Answer (score -3):

Tab. Or do you still want to see your tools even though you're using shortcuts?

Comment: Hi kamalo, can you explain how hiding panels, which is what tab does, is useful to this question? It doesn't seem to be even in the general ballpark.

Comment: Tab hides all tools, if he's using short cuts already, he can adjust the view by toggling the tools on an off. (but I have a hunch that you already knew that) Since Adobe doesn't offer short cut assignments or even the capability to script this, I believe that I've provided the best possible answer for his question.

Comment: Okay..if you say so....  I still don't see what hiding panels has to do with layer group expansion states.